# Xamarin - Fix freezing ProgressDialog

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an app that make use of ProgressDialog. But the problem is that everytime i call my webservice, the loading icon freeze(stops spinning) until i get a response from my web service. How can i overcome this ?

Below is my code :

```
ProgressDialog pdLoading;

 pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(this);
 pdLoading.SetMessage("Submiting your query. Please wait...");
 pdLoading.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
 pdLoading.Show();


 //send to server
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 var jsonParameter = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
 var content = new StringContent(jsonParameter.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//The progress dialog freezes when it calls this method
HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsync(WsClasses.GetWsLink() + "/XXX/value1", content).Result;
```

**I also tried the following solution**

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(object inputData, string wsLink)
{
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var jsonParameter = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputData);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonParameter.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(wsLink, content);

            if (client != null)
                client.Dispose();

            if (pdLoading != null)
                pdLoading.Dismiss();

            return result;
   }
```

Comment: don't call your webservice from the UI thread

Comment: Jason is right.  You need to run these calls on a separate thread and then rejoin the main thread to remove the loading icon.

Comment: You suggestion worked Jason. Wrapped the background code with Tast.Factory.StartNew(()=>{  code here }; .  I show progressdiag in the main thread, and stop it in the new thread(Tast.Factory).

Answer (score 0):

use await not .result.  Await will allow the app to run while calling the web service.  The .result will cause the app to freeze while calling the web service

```
 HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(WsClasses.GetWsLink() + "/XXX/value1", content)
```

Comment: The progress dialog loading icon still freeze. This time it freezes(for +-2 seconds) when it receives information from the server.